# Wrong type of parameter passed

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a *base* module and in this module I have an interface:

```
interface BaseNavigationInterface : Serializable{

fun onItemClicked(navItemId: Int)
}
```

I have a *market* module and in this module I have an activity with this static method:

```
companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    fun newIntent(context: Context, navInterface: BaseNavigationInterface) : Intent {
        var intent = Intent(context, MarketActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("interface", navInterface)
        return intent
    }
}
```

In my other module (this is the *app* module) I would like to start the *market* module like this:

```
startActivity(MarketActivity.newIntent(this, navigationInterface));
```

And navigationInterface is a class variable in my activity:

```
private BaseNavigationInterface navigationInterface = (BaseNavigationInterface)(new BaseNavigationInterface() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClicked(int navItemId) {

    }
});
```

My problem is that when my program calls the startActivity() method and it calls the MarketActivity.newIntent() method the type of the navigationInterface parameter is the MainActivity.
Why?

[image]

I got this exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = my.app.activities.MainActivity$9)

The same code in pure kotlin project is working fine, but now I have a mixed project. (app module is java, and the oders are kotlin modules)

Comment: I'm not sure making your interface BaseNavigationInterface inherit Serializable really make it serializable cf. doc : 'The subtype may assume this responsibility only if the class it extends has an accessible no-arg constructor to initialize the class's state. It is an error to declare a class Serializable if this is not the case.' https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a serializable callback you may use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ResultReceiver.html

```
ResultReceiver receiver = new ResultReceiver(new Handler()) {
    protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
       val navItemId: Int = resultData.get...
    }
}

intent.putExtra("interface", receiver )
```

Comment: I don't want a serializable callback, I just want to find the best way to communicate between modules without circular dependecy. Do you know a better solution for this?